# Executing two FOR SELECT statement in SP firebird

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, firebird

Is it possible to have 2 FOR SELECT statement in stored procedure where the 1st statement will display all of its data then the 2nd statement will continue when the 1st statement is done .

I already tried this one:

```
for select id,date,particular
from TABLE_NAME
  into :id, :date, :particular
do begin
  suspend;
end

for select id,date,payor
from TABLE_NAME
  into :id, :date, :payor
do begin
   suspend;
end
```

the first statement performs well but the second statement displays some data of the column particular of the 1st statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, but there are two things you need to take into account:

1. A selectable stored procedure only has **one** result set, so for the client it is not possible to detect this without some kind of discriminator column.
2. If you don't reassign a value, the last assigned value is returned for each subsequent row.

This second item is the problem you are having, to solve this, you need to clear the value of `particular`, eg by adding the line `particular = null;` between the first and select `for select ..` block:

```
for select id,date,particular
from TABLE_NAME
  into :id, :date, :particular
do begin
  suspend;
end

particular = null;

for select id,date,payor
from TABLE_NAME
  into :id, :date, :payor
do begin
   suspend;
end
```

However if the code in your question is the actual code, you might want to consider using a view instead with two selects combined with `union all`. This is likely to have less overhead.